# Using AJAX to send data to Coder Igniter controller function results in a 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, internal-server-error

I am trying to use AJAX to send data from a Code Igniter view to a controller that will handle the data as needed. I'm gathering the data using a JQuery plugin (Handsontable) and when the user hits the "save" button it extracts the required data from the table and executes the ajax function.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/survey/save",
    data: {"data": data},
    type: "POST",
});
```

I am able to send it to a regular .php file which collects the data with $_POST but not my controller.

```
public function save() {
    $data = $this->input->post('data');

    $myFile = "testFile.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");    

    for ($i = 0, $size = count($data); $i < $size; ++$i) {
        fwrite($fh, $data[$i][0]."\t".$data[$i][1]."\t".$data[$i][2]."\n");
    }
    fclose($fh);
}
```

The above code is not what I really want the controller to do but if can successfully execute this code, I will be able to do what I wish.

I have a feeling it has something to do with the URL of the ajax function but I am extremely new to all of these languages and am probably overlooking something simple. Please let me know if I should include any other code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question in case it helps others. The problem was my csrf settings. I realized turning off csrf protection fixed the problem but I didn't want to keep csrf protection off. I think CI may have came out with a whitelist to fix this but I just edited my config file as follows:

```
if(stripos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'/survey') === FALSE)
{
    $config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
}
else
{
    $config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey you have to change in `ajax url` The format of url must be **absolute path** for e.g.

In your **view** the ajax should be like this

```
$.ajax({
        url:'<?php echo site_url('survey/save'); ?>',
        type: 'post',
        data:  "data="+data,
        beforeSend:function(){
                //before send code for e.g. put a loader
        },
        success:function(result){ 
            // success result code goes here
        },
        error:function(jqXHR, status, error){
            if(status!='error')
                alert(error);   
        }
    });
```

Now in your **controller** you can get the data

```
$data=$this->input->post('data');
```

and one more thing you have to use **relative path** when your using `fopen` for e.g.

//you have used

```
$myFile = "testFile.txt";

//instead of that you have to use

$myFile="./YOUR_FOLDER_NAME/YOUR_FILE_NAME";
```

and you can set in your **config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

Comment: I have implemented the changes you have suggested but I am still getting and Internal Server Error. Through the console I can preview the survey/save page and it is giving me an error through Code Igniter. "An Error Was Encountered The action you have requested is not allowed."

Comment: Figured it out. Had to do with my csrf settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you have done your config file in the CI Application/Config folder

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://yourwebsite.com/';
```

then for your url it is

```
"<?php echo base_url();?>survey/save",
```

Answer (score 0):

The very simple and easy way try this code:

first you must have set your base_url in application/confiq.php
or with .htaccess

your script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var base_url = '<?=base_url()?>';

function m_ajax()
{
   var ids = $("#all_users").val();

   $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url: base_url+"history/home/get_users",
      data: "userid=" + ids,
      success: function(result){
        $("#m_ajax").html(result);
    }
    });

}
</script>
```

in your controller you can get the value of userid as post

```
 $userid = $this->input->post('userid');
```

and you can perform other operations according.